is there a limit to the amount of text in raylib?
I've been playing with raylib, drewing circles with smiley-faces, but after 390 circles on the screen everything disappears, if instead of characters >_<, I draw just character > then you can fit 430 circles.
What might be the reason?
Here's the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <raylib.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH  800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

#define CIRCLES_CAPACITY 1024

// why??
#define CIRCLES_MAX 390

int main(void)
{
    Vector2 circles[CIRCLES_CAPACITY] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < CIRCLES_MAX - 2; i++) {
        // coordinates does not matter
        circles[i] = (Vector2){SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.5f, SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.5f};
    }
    size_t circles_len = CIRCLES_MAX - 2;

    InitWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "test");
    //SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        DrawFPS(10, 10);

        // add new circle when user left click
        if (IsMouseButtonPressed(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT)) {
            if (circles_len + 1 < CIRCLES_CAPACITY) {
                circles[circles_len++] = (Vector2){GetMouseX(), GetMouseY()};
            }
        }
        // render circles
        for (size_t i = 0; i < circles_len; i++) {

            // draw a circle
            DrawCircleV(circles[i], 25, YELLOW);

            // >_<
            const char* smile_str = ">_<";
            Vector2 smile_size = MeasureTextEx(GetFontDefault(), smile_str, 32, 0);

            // this line causes strange behaviour i think
            // draw a text on the circle
            DrawText(smile_str, (int)(circles[i].x - smile_size.x*0.5f - 3), (int)(circles[i].y - smile_size.y*0.5f), 32, BLACK);
        }

        // print count of circles
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_C)) {
            printf("Count of circles: %zu\n", circles_len);
        }

        ClearBackground(BLACK);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}

Before
After

Debug to see if statement smile_size.x*0.5f - 3 for case > gets negative or not. I think so.

Nope, it's positive, I debugged this, also you can add if statements to prevent this situation but the same bug appears

The strange thing is that after 390 circles all other shapes disappear (if you drew them), even the fps counter, but new circles keep appearing correctly (except the 390th, it's corrupted), if you add a hotkey that resets circles_len, everything comes back to normal again and i don't understand why
example:

example:
before
after

I've never used raylib, but you have ClearBackground just before EndDrawing() rather than just after BeginDrawing(), which strikes me as wrong, but I don't understand how it can result in you being able to see anything at all..

thanks!! i totally missed that, everything works now
